# remove php extension from url having query string variable using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a url like:

```
http://exploreinfo/controller/register.php?key=hjgsaf1
```

where I want the url like:

```
http://exploreinfo/controller/register/?key=hjgsaf1
```

how to remove php with the above format using `.htaccess` in php

Comment: [how to remove php extensions with htaccess](http://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/)

Comment: A quick search on [google](https://www.google.ro/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=htaccess%20remove%20.php) returns lots of articles on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

create a .htaccess file or use apache rewrite: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

The rule is :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^register/$ register.php [QSA]
```